# How do I add a string at the end of another string if there is not match using sub

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to add  `string1` to the end of an `string2` if `string2` does not include `string1`.

Can I do this using `sub`?

I tried a few combinations but they are not doing anything. I'm not even sure I'm doing it right. I'm very bad at Regex and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: show us those combination :)

Comment: If "I tried a few combinations but they are not doing anything", then show us what you tried so we can help correct your code, rather than write new and totally unrelated code that you then have to shoehorn into place.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a `sub`? you can just do something like:

```
a = "abcd"
b = "bc"

c = a + b unless a.include?(b)
```

Comment: Or `a << b unless a[b]`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you'd use this pattern:

```
string = "test"
insert = "er"

string << insert unless (string.match(insert))
# => "tester"
```